# Does dlib provide goodness of fit?

Tags: data-fitting, dlib

I'm using dlib with Qt in c++. After fitting an error function to data using the least_squares_lm algorithm, I would like to assess the goodness of the fit by having some value returned.

Can the dlib library return some goodness of fit parameter? 
Or do I have to calculate them myself?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in dlib for this, like [r_squared](http://dlib.net/algorithms.html#r_squared).  But it really depends on what you want to do.